# scope variable not updating template

Tags: angularjs

I have html structure like this, grid.message.success is not being shown

```
<div ng-controller="MYAPPCtrl">
    ....
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    ....
        <div ng-controller="GridCtrl>
            <div ng-show="grid.message.success" class="success-msg">{{grid.message.success}}</div>
            <div ng-show="grid.message.error" class="error-msg">{{grid.message.error}}</div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="deleteUsers()"... />
     </div>
</div>
```

here is my js code

```
function MYAPPCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.gridMessage = {
        success: null,
        error: null
    }

    $scope.setGridMessage = function(d) {
        $scope.gridMessage = d;
    }
}
function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.deleteUsers = function() {
        $scope.setGridMessage({success: 'hello'});
    })
}
function GridCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.grid = {
    message: $scope.gridMessage,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the template, it's not `grid.message` you need to bind to, but `gridMessage`.

Update your template to:

```
<div ng-controller="MYAPPCtrl">
    ....
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    ....
        <div ng-controller="GridCtrl>
            <div ng-show="gridMessage.success" class="success-msg">{{gridMessage.success}}</div>
            <div ng-show="gridMessage.error" class="error-msg">{{gridMessage.error}}</div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="deleteUsers()"... />
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

After `$scope.setGridMessage({success: 'hello'});` call, `$scope.grid.message` **still** holds the reference to the old object. To resolve the issue, you can use `angular.extend` method, in order to update `gridMessage`, not create new one:

```
$scope.setGridMessage = function(d) {
   angular.extend($scope.gridMessage,d);
}
```